# Bad index issues while populating a matrix from an array by rows, columns or randomly

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, indexing

Let you have a `std::vector< T >` (where by `T` I mean any class or typename) containing `n` elements and you want to populate a matrix-like object, as instance an object of class `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix< T >`, whose dimensionality is `m1` rows and `m2` columns, inserting those elements one by one by rows or by columns.

First of all, it must be `n <= m1 * m2` or we're trying to fill, say, 10 slots with 11 or more elements; then: if `n <= m1` (respectively, `n <= m2`) no problems arise for a loop is enough.

But if `n > m1` (`n > m2`) you have to split your `std::vector< T >` to avoid bad index issues and to populate your matrix according to your choice.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <vector>

template < class T > inline void PopulateGrid(const std::vector< T >& tVector,
                                              boost::numeric::ublas::matrix< T >& tMatrix,
                                              char by = 'n')
{
    if (tVector.size() > tMatrix.size1() * tMatrix.size2())
        throw("Matrix is too small to contain all the array elements!");
    else
    {
        switch(by)
        {
        case 'r' :
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < tMatrix.size1(); i++)
            {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < tVector.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (j <= tMatrix.size2())
                        tMatrix(i, j) = tVector[j];
                    else
                        tMatrix(i + 1, j - tMatrix.size2()) = tVector[j];
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'c' :
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < tMatrix.size2(); j++)
            {
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < tVector.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (i <= tMatrix.size1())
                        tMatrix(i, j) = tVector[i];
                    else
                        tMatrix(i - tMatrix.size1(), j + 1) = tVector[j];
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < tMatrix.size1(); i++)
            {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < tVector.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (j <= tMatrix.size2())
                        tMatrix(i, j) = tVector[j];
                    else
                        tMatrix(i + 1, j - tMatrix.size2()) = tVector[j];
                }
            }
            // Following is just to populate it randomly
            std::random_shuffle(tMatrix.begin1(), tMatrix.end1());
            std::random_shuffle(tMatrix.begin2(), tMatrix.end2());
        }
    }
}
```

A fast main to try it:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector< int > ciao;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        ciao.push_back(i);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix< int > peppa(10, 10);
    PopulateGrid< int >(ciao, peppa); // crashes!

   /* Check failed in file C:\DevTools\boost_1_54_0/boost/numeric/ublas/functional.hpp
    * at line 1371:
    *    j < size_j
    * terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::ublas::bad_index'
    *    what():  bad index
    */

    return 0;
}
```

The point is: I am missing some easier operations on indexes to achieve the same result and I am messing with indexes.

Comment: In the fifth row, you mean "n <= m1*m2", I guess?

Comment: `char by = 'rand'` What does this mean? char stores a single character only.

Comment: You can't use a string in a switch statement in that way. I suggest you use an enum.

Comment: Now it should be correct, albeit not the point of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will completely re-write this answer, it's more of an answer and less of a suggestion now.

Again, the problem you have is here:

```
for (unsigned j = 0; j < tVector.size(); j++) {
  if (j <= tMatrix.size2())
    tMatrix(i, j) = tVector[j];
  else
    tMatrix(i + 1, j - tMatrix.size2()) = tVector[j];
}
```

This is the inner loop of the nested for-loop construct that you are using. In here, you run through the entire vector. Upon j exceeding size2 you are not exiting the loop, but instead adressing (i+1) as the first index for tMatrix(i1,i2). And then for i2 you subtract size2 from j.

Two problems: As soon as your j exceeds size2 you will forever rewrite into the matrix i1 index of value 1. 
And then, if j becomes greater than 2*size2 you will try writing out of bound indicies. For example, if the vecor contains 20 elements and you have a 7*7 matrix, you will write to vectorIndex-7 as soon as vectorIndex becomes 8. [Note that your <=tMatrix.size2() is also wrong, should be only < ). That works all the way until vectorIndex is 14 or greater, as 14-7 = 7 or great -> out of bound.

Second problem is that your outer for-loop will still do its iteration and recall the entire process for every i-value. In the end you will be at the maximum allowed i-value and in your inner loop you will try accessing (i+1). This will also give you an out of bound expection.

I would suggest something like this as a solution:

```
for ( std::vector<T>::iterator it = yourVector.begin(), int rowIndex = 0, colmIndex = 0; 
      it != yourVector.end(); ++it, colmIndex++ ) {

      if ( colmIndex >= yourMatrix.size2() ) {
          rowIndex++;
          colmIndex = 0;
          yourMatrix (rowIndex, colmIndex ) = *it;
      }
      else {
          yourMatrix (rowIndex, colmIndex ) = *it;
      }

  }
```

This is untested and fills the vector by column. You should be able to figure out what to do for byRow yourself!

Comment: As of the first solution you proposed, i.e. single loop with proper logic, how would you do that?

Comment: What you are already doing, but counting up the j-value properly. Currently you just adress (j+1) value, which, in your case, will forever be 1.

You need to save the result of the incremenation, aka j++. But then you also need to take care of the second index. I would not do an abitrary subtraction, i would keep track of both matrix-indicies that you need. If you exceed row or coloumn, reset the corresponding index to 0. 
So you have lets say vectorIndex, colmnIndex, rowIndex. vectorIndex runs through the vector and along this process you adjust rowIndex and colmIndex to your needs.Got that?

Comment: I will add an example to my answer when I'm done picking up heavy weight from the floor and lifting them against gravity.

Comment: I edited my answer to now contain actual code, also rewrote the whole explanation once more.

Comment: I am trying your solution, but at the first line I get the following error: `error: need 'typename' before 'std::vector<T>::iterator' because 'std::vector<T>' is a dependent scope`.

Comment: There should be the word `typename` before `std::vector<T>::iterator`. Even so, however, this doesn't work due to `error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'`...

Comment: In addition: declaring all integers and the iterator before the switch, I get `error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = (& tVector)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<int, std::allocator<int> >()'|`

Comment: Aside from these, the main point (the algorithm) is ok... thank you!

Comment: Oh yea, it's been a while as i am stuck to Java development currently (work), so it's all a  little rusty. Could you please edit your original post with your current code? I will review it as soon as i am home and have acess to an IDE.